# SQL logs filling up with "Setting database option Compatibility_Level" messages

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs

On several of my servers, I have "Setting database option Compatibility_Level" messages filling up the SQL log and application event log to the tune of twice every 5 seconds. This makes finding anything *else* in the SQL log nearly impossible.

I'm aware that this is [a known bug in MS Reporting Services](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/488169/setting-database-option-compatibility-level-to-100-for-reportserver) (marked "Closed as Won't Fix"). I'm looking for other ideas to resolve this. Using profiler, I found the code being run by the reporting server is:

```
DECLARE @currVer nvarchar(128), @currMajorVer nvarchar(32)
     , @idx int, @currMajorVerInt tinyint ;

SELECT @currVer = CONVERT(nvarchar(128), ServerProperty('ProductVersion')) ;
SET @idx = CHARINDEX('.', @currVer, 0) ;
SET @currMajorVer = SUBSTRING(@currVer, 1, @idx-1) ;
SET @currMajorVerInt = CONVERT(tinyint, @currMajorVer) ;

DECLARE @dbname sysname

IF @currMajorVerInt =  10
BEGIN       
    SELECT @dbname=DB_NAME()
    EXEC sp_dbcmptlevel @dbname, 100 ;      
END
```

Ideas?

The listed "workaround" suggested modifying the system stored procedure `sp_dbcmptlevel`, which [although possible](http://www.slaviks-blog.com/2010/08/19/changing-ms-sql-server-system-stored-procedures/), is not recommended for a variety of good reasons.

[Another thread on this issue](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/474f0c72-95b0-4fe3-8f3c-b7b7e500bd4f) suggested changing the system account used by the reporting services service. I'm not sure if that applies to our situation. Has anyone found that this resolves the issue for you?

Only other idea I had: is there any way to intercept and either block a query from being executed, or to alter the syntax of the query before it is executed? Like a kind of INSTEAD TRIGGER or something?

Answer (score 2):

Only a couple of things come to mind.

1. Hack sp_dbcmptlevel and add a "IF suser_sname() = 'Your SSRS Account' RETURN" to the very top of it.
2. Add a DDL trigger to the database that simply rolls back any alter database statements.

There's no way to intercept the database call and prevent it from being sent to the database engine.

Comment: The listed workaround modifies `sp_dbcmptlevel` by adding `if @input_cmptlevel = @new_cmptlevel' to make sure its not already at the level you're trying to switch to. Not sure about hacking system procs, though. I like the DLL trigger idea, will investigate it to see if that might work, will need to exclude other possibly valid ALTER DATABASE types...

Comment: I didn't say it was a good idea, just an idea. :)

Comment: Hmm, finding links that say that ALTER_DATABASE triggers don't always roll back. Guess I will have to test. Also not sure if returning an error message to Reporting Services from the trigger will cause an "unhandled exception" error on the website.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to return an error to SSRS, just silently return from sp_dbcmptlevel.

Comment: Didn't mention anything about returning an error. Just bail out of the procedure so that SSRS thinks that it ran successfully.